# Why is that an EC2 strong comupter gives close results to a 16gb ram laptop

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, benchmarking

How can it be that m4.4xlarge EC2 computer with 64GB RAM and 16 logical cores has almost the same results as my 16GB RAM laptop that has 4 logical cores?
I used benchmark package for the test (attached below).
Is there any way to better configure the m4.4xlarge EC2 computer? 
This is the system info for m4.4xlarge EC2 computer

```
Sys.info()
             sysname              release              version 
           "Windows" "Server >= 2012 x64"         "build 9200" 
            nodename              machine                login 
   "EC2AMAZ-4R7L3U6"             "x86-64"      "Administrator" 
                user       effective_user 
     "Administrator"      "Administrator" 
> library("parallel", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library")
> detectCores(logical = FALSE)
[1] 8
> detectCores(logical = TRUE)
[1] 16
```

This is my laptop's system info:

```
 Sys.info()
                     sysname                      release                      version 
                   "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1" 
                    nodename                      machine                        login 
                   "USER-PC"                     "x86-64"                       "user" 
                        user               effective_user 
                      "user"                       "user" 
> detectCores(logical = TRUE)
[1] 4
> detectCores(logical = FALSE)
[1] 2
```

The test results are:
For the m4.4xlarge EC2 computer:

```
> benchmark_std()

    user system elapsed          test test_group cores
1   1.02   0.02    1.03           fib       prog     0
2   0.75   0.00    0.75           fib       prog     0
3   0.77   0.00    0.77           fib       prog     0
4   1.34   0.07    1.41           gcd       prog     0
5   1.20   0.06    1.27           gcd       prog     0
6   1.05   0.08    1.12           gcd       prog     0
7   0.19   0.02    0.21       hilbert       prog     0
8   0.34   0.02    0.36       hilbert       prog     0
9   0.35   0.02    0.36       hilbert       prog     0
10 16.37   0.03   16.40      toeplitz       prog     0
11 16.46   0.00   16.46      toeplitz       prog     0
12 16.37   0.00   16.37      toeplitz       prog     0
13  1.41   0.04    1.44     escoufier       prog     0
14  1.25   0.00    1.25     escoufier       prog     0
15  1.27   0.00    1.27     escoufier       prog     0
16  0.91   0.01    0.92         manip matrix_cal     0
17  0.92   0.02    0.94         manip matrix_cal     0
18  0.78   0.00    0.78         manip matrix_cal     0
19  1.01   0.02    1.03         power matrix_cal     0
20  1.03   0.00    1.03         power matrix_cal     0
21  1.03   0.02    1.04         power matrix_cal     0
22  0.82   0.00    0.83          sort matrix_cal     0
23  0.81   0.02    0.83          sort matrix_cal     0
24  0.80   0.03    0.83          sort matrix_cal     0
25  8.83   0.00    8.83 cross_product matrix_cal     0
26  8.83   0.01    8.85 cross_product matrix_cal     0
27  8.85   0.02    8.86 cross_product matrix_cal     0
28  5.92   0.01    5.93            lm matrix_cal     0
29  5.92   0.00    5.92            lm matrix_cal     0
30  5.90   0.02    5.93            lm matrix_cal     0
31  5.17   0.02    5.18      cholesky matrix_fun     0
32  5.03   0.02    5.05      cholesky matrix_fun     0
33  5.03   0.01    5.04      cholesky matrix_fun     0
34  2.89   0.00    2.89   determinant matrix_fun     0
35  2.84   0.00    2.84   determinant matrix_fun     0
36  2.87   0.00    2.87   determinant matrix_fun     0
37  0.73   0.00    0.73         eigen matrix_fun     0
38  0.74   0.00    0.74         eigen matrix_fun     0
39  0.73   0.00    0.74         eigen matrix_fun     0
40  0.28   0.00    0.28           fft matrix_fun     0
41  0.28   0.00    0.29           fft matrix_fun     0
42  0.28   0.00    0.29           fft matrix_fun     0
43  2.14   0.02    2.17       inverse matrix_fun     0
44  2.17   0.00    2.17       inverse matrix_fun     0
45  2.16   0.00    2.16       inverse matrix_fun     0
```

For the 16GB laptop:

```
    user system elapsed          test test_group cores
1   0.67   0.00    0.67           fib       prog     0
2   0.69   0.00    0.68           fib       prog     0
3   0.67   0.00    0.67           fib       prog     0
4   1.20   0.05    1.26           gcd       prog     0
5   1.18   0.02    1.20           gcd       prog     0
6   1.22   0.01    1.23           gcd       prog     0
7   0.52   0.02    0.53       hilbert       prog     0
8   0.48   0.05    0.53       hilbert       prog     0
9   0.25   0.01    0.27       hilbert       prog     0
10 16.08   0.00   16.18      toeplitz       prog     0
11 18.87   0.00   18.90      toeplitz       prog     0
12 16.81   0.00   16.86      toeplitz       prog     0
13  1.17   0.00    1.17     escoufier       prog     0
14  1.21   0.00    1.22     escoufier       prog     0
15  1.19   0.00    1.21     escoufier       prog     0
16  0.95   0.00    0.95         manip matrix_cal     0
17  1.14   0.05    1.19         manip matrix_cal     0
18  0.67   0.03    0.72         manip matrix_cal     0
19  0.86   0.00    0.85         power matrix_cal     0
20  0.89   0.00    0.89         power matrix_cal     0
21  0.87   0.00    0.88         power matrix_cal     0
22  0.75   0.00    0.75          sort matrix_cal     0
23  0.71   0.03    0.75          sort matrix_cal     0
24  0.71   0.00    0.73          sort matrix_cal     0
25  7.99   0.00    8.01 cross_product matrix_cal     0
26  7.96   0.07    8.03 cross_product matrix_cal     0
27  7.96   0.00    7.97 cross_product matrix_cal     0
28  5.38   0.00    5.41            lm matrix_cal     0
29  5.50   0.00    5.49            lm matrix_cal     0
30  5.50   0.00    5.51            lm matrix_cal     0
31  4.55   0.03    4.63      cholesky matrix_fun     0
32  4.68   0.00    4.73      cholesky matrix_fun     0
33  4.54   0.02    4.60      cholesky matrix_fun     0
34  3.06   0.00    3.11   determinant matrix_fun     0
35  3.41   0.00    3.42   determinant matrix_fun     0
36  3.44   0.00    3.46   determinant matrix_fun     0
37  0.98   0.00    0.99         eigen matrix_fun     0
38  0.79   0.00    0.79         eigen matrix_fun     0
39  1.03   0.00    1.06         eigen matrix_fun     0
40  0.40   0.00    0.42           fft matrix_fun     0
41  0.39   0.00    0.39           fft matrix_fun     0
42  0.39   0.00    0.39           fft matrix_fun     0
43  2.75   0.00    2.74       inverse matrix_fun     0
44  2.70   0.00    2.79       inverse matrix_fun     0
45  2.70   0.00    2.69       inverse matrix_fun     0
```

Comment: AS Fabien noted, you aren't using the memory and R will only use a single core unless you deliberately parallelize operations. The benchmark suite doesn't test that. This is also discussed at length in numerous posts abt R and even newer books abt R.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, Is there any way to better configure the m4.4xlarge EC2 computer?

Comment: @mql4beginner better configure it for what exactly? The software running the benchmark is the issue here, not the EC2 instance itself. If you want to understand the difference between your laptop and the EC2 instance then you should try running 16 instances of the benchmark software **at the same time** on each. In other words, your benchmark software needs to actually take advantage of the extra RAM and CPU cores if you want to see an actual difference in the benchmark numbers.

Comment: We also have no idea what problems you're trying to solve @mql4beginner.  It sounds like you shld take a few hours and go through the various resources in [this CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benchmarks seem to be computing mathematical functions that aren't easy to parallelize, so it's likely that they aren't parallelized.

Which means that only one CPU core will do the work.

Thus, the number of cores in your computer (virtual or not) won't affect the performance, only the core's speed will.
Your laptop seems a little bit slower than the EC2 computer, which seems expected given the expected speed difference of a a single core.

Then, since one can't just "speed up" the EC2 computers (they're already running as fast as they can), you simply can't get better results with these benchmarks. Try another benchmark that does some parallel processing, and you'll see the huge benefits of an EC2 instance VS. your laptop.

Comment: Thank you @Fabien Viger, Is there a way to set the clock speed in EC2?

Comment: @mql4beginner You realize EC2 instances are virtual machines right? If you want faster clock speeds then you should look at the compute optimized C5 instance types: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/